# Quotation marks for queries

Tags: r

If I use this:

```
web<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/li[@class='ode acs er cart']")
```

it works perfect. If I try to use a variable which contains the sting:

```
myvar <- "/'ode acs er cart/'"
web<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/li[@class=myvar]")
```

it doesn't work. Is there anything I am doing wrong with quotation marks?

Comment: The variable name "myvar" is read as part of the string, and not as a variable. Consider using paste("//*/li[@class=", myvar, sep = "")

Answer (score 0):

`myvar` is a variable, not a string. Using it accordingly is better:

```
myvar <- "/'ode acs er cart/'"
x <- paste0("//*/li[@class=", mylar, "]")
web<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', x)
```

You may not use `x` as a variable:

```
myvar <- "/'ode acs er cart/'"
web<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', paste0("//*/li[@class=", myvar, "]"))
```